# How can I get this result?

Tags: php, mysql, string, yii2, pivot

For example I have table

```
+----+---------+
| gid|  name   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | stan    |
|  1 | kyle    |
|  2 | kenny   |
|  3 | cartman |
|  3 | john    |
|  3 | myley   |
+----+---------+
```

I need this result:

```
+----+-------------+
|  1 |  2  |  3    |
|stan|kenny|cartman|
|kyle|null |john   | 
|null|null |myley  |
+----+-------------+
```

as array:

```
[
 [1,2,3],
 [stan,kenny, cartman],
 [kyle, null, john],  
 [null,null,myley]
]
```

If it's not possible in MYSQL than how to do this using arrays in PHP? Thanks

Comment: As mentioned, while possible in sql, it's simpler (and more easily scalable) in php

Comment: This seems quite confusing as a requirement.  It's weird to have rows of data where the columns have no actual relation to each other.  If you're just trying to display it somewhere why not loop through each distinct gid?  

Does the order of the results matter?  Would a valid result be for column one to have values Kyle, Stan, NULL instead?

Comment: thanks for all the answers, appreciate it! I will go trying in PHP though, as it looks too complicated through sql.

Comment: Found great solution based on this topic
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028148/php-array-to-csv-by-column

Answer (score 2):

If you have mysql 8 you can use the first

But when you have a flexible number of guis you can use the second, which makes a pivot table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `gid` INTEGER,
>   `name` VARCHAR(7)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`gid`, `name`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'stan'),
>   ('1', 'kyle'),
>   ('2', 'kenny'),
>   ('3', 'cartman'),
>   ('3', 'john'),
>   ('3', 'myley');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> MAX(IF (`gid` = 1,  `name`, NULL)) as '1',
> MAX(IF (`gid` = 2,  `name`, NULL)) as '2',
> MAX(IF (`gid` = 3,  `name`, NULL)) as '3'
> FrOM
> (SELECT *,
>        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
>           PARTITION BY `gid`
>           ) row_num
>           FROM table1) t1
> GROUP BY row_num
> ```
>
> ```
> 1    | 2     | 3      
> :--- | :---- | :------
> stan | kenny | cartman
> kyle | null  | john   
> null | null  | myley
> ```

> ```
> SET @sql = NULL;
> SELECT
>   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>                CONCAT('MAX(IF (`gid` = "', `gid`,'", `name`,"")) AS "',gid,'"')
>               ) INTO @sql
> FROM (SELECT *,
>        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
>           PARTITION BY `gid`
>           ) row_num
>           FROM table1) t1;
>
>
> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT   ', @sql, ' 
>                   FROM (SELECT *,
>        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
>           PARTITION BY `gid`
>           ) row_num
>           FROM table1) t1
>                  GROUP BY row_num
>                  ');
> #SELECT @sql;
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DEALLOCATE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
> 1    | 2     | 3      
> :--- | :---- | :------
> stan | kenny | cartman
> kyle |       | john   
>      |       | myley
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ab8074fe5c2649864da5f156302a4ec)*

Answer (score 0):

Such possible would probably be better handled on application side... But is is doable in SQL, using window functions (available in MySQL 8.0):

```
select
    max(case when gid = 1 then name end) name1,
    max(case when gid = 2 then name end) name2,
    max(case when gid = 3 then name end) name3
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by gid order by name) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by rn
```